# Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 4 Ambiguous column name 'p_id'

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following query which is generating the error message

> Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 4 Ambiguous column name 'p_id'

Below is the offending query.

```
SELECT *
from (select playerperform.p_id,player.first_name, SUM (playerperform.score)as totalgoal, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY SUM(playerperform.score)DESC) Rnk
      from playerperform,player  
      Group by p_id
      )as a
WHERE Rnk = 1
```

Comment: i want to put player name but it gives me this error

Comment: sir i want to put player name also how can i put that? player name is in other table call "Player"

Answer (score 1):

Clearly you have a `p_id` column in both `playerperform` and `player`.

At the very minimum, change:

```
GROUP BY p_id
```

To

```
GROUP BY playerperform.p_id
```

It also seems suspicious that you are performing an implicit `CROSS JOIN`:

```
FROM playerperform,player
```

I suspect that should be an `INNER JOIN` with some condition, such as

```
FROM dbo.playerperform INNER JOIN dbo.player
ON playerperform.p_id = player.p_id
```

As an aside, `p_id` is a terrible name for a column...

Comment: sorry i cant understand

Comment: @user2914820 Sorry, but if you can't understand my answer, then I don't know how else to help you.

Comment: SELECT * from (select playerperform.p_id, player.first_name+last_name, SUM (playerperform.score)as totalgoal, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY SUM(playerperform.score)DESC) Rnk from playerperform INNER JOIN player ON playerperform.p_id = player.p_id Group by playerperform.p_id,player.first_name+last_name )as a WHERE Rnk = 1

Comment: these are my codes <<  i want to put player name also how can i put that? player name is in other table call "Player"